# What are the benefits of using asyncio.gather?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write some asynchronous code. I started with a public code like the following:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


urls = ['www.example.com/1', 'www.example.com/2', ...]
tasks = []


async def fetch(url, session) -> str:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.text()


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, session)))

        response = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


asyncio.run(main())
```

I realized that there is another way to get the same result by writing `main()` as below:

```
async def main_2():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, session)))

        response = []
        for t in tasks:
            response.append(await t)
```

Both methods take same time to finish. So, while processing responses inside `main_2()` is so easy, what are the benefits of using asyncio.gather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages:

1. It automatically schedules any coroutines as tasks for you. If you hadn't been creating the tasks manually, the non-`gather` approach wouldn't even start running them until you tried to `await` them (losing all the benefits of async processing), where `gather` would create tasks for all of them up-front then `await` them in bulk.
2. When using `return_exceptions=False` (the default), you'll know when something has gone wrong immediately; with the loop, you might process dozens of results before one turns out to have failed. This may or may not be advantageous, depending on your needs. `asyncio.as_completed` may serve better in certain cases (getting results in completion order, as soon as they come in, rather than waiting for everything to finish), it depends on needs.
3. If you save off the `gather` to a name before `await`ing it, you can bulk cancel any outstanding tasks when an exception occurs and `return_exceptions=False` (just `try:`/`except Exception: gathername.cancel()`, without needing to know *which* tasks need canceling).

Personally, I usually find `asyncio.as_completed` more useful, in the same way `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` is nicer than `multiprocessing.Pool.map` (because result ordering rarely matters, and it's nice to process results immediately as they become available), but `asyncio.gather` is the simpler "all-in-one, wait for everything before continuing" interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've another question: What are the differences between `for url in urls: tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(url))) resp = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`  and`resp = await asyncio.gather(*(fetch(url) for url in urls))`?

Comment: @Babak: The only difference is that the former gives you access to the `list` of tasks, and that, by creating the tasks immediately, if you `await`ed anything between the `append` loop and the `gather` call, some of those tasks could begin running. If you don't need the tasks themselves, and don't `await` between the loop and the `gather` call, the two are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry but I confused about `awaiting anything between the append loop and the gather call`. Could you please give some example of this approach? As far as I have seen, many of the codes are the same as the former without anything between the loop and gather call.

Comment: @Babak: I have no idea what you're looking for here. If you `await`ed some other, unrelated thing in between, the tasks could run. Literally, that's the example. It could be `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, it doesn't matter, as long as it blocks, returning control to the event loop which would allow it to do other things.